# Visual studio 2010 and C# v.4

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

A few days ago VS 2010 went in Beta test and usually with new Visual Studio ,we get new C#.

Since VS and .NET 4 is in Beta does that mean that C# version four is near to the finish?

Edit: is C# v4 Beta included in the VS 2010 beta?

Comment: Your post looks more like a release announcement than a real question...

Comment: Why do you to close my question? Its not subjective and its somehow programming related.

Comment: Well,I'm asking about C# v4,does it mean that C# v4 is included in the VS 2010 beta?

Comment: I didn't close. I just voted for it. To close a question, at least five people should vote. I feel this is not a real question (which is one of the close reasons). So it's just my vote. It's up to the community to decide.

Comment: This is a fair question I believe, although it doesn't have a very satisfying answer.

Comment: @John: Please include that in your question. Yes, it's included, by the way.

Comment: This does actually seem to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440156/when-is-net-4-0-and-visual-studio-2010-supposed-to-be-released

Comment: @Noldorin - to be fair, the dup doesn't mention C# 4.0, and the 4 things [CLR/.NET/C#/VS] have all previously been versioned independently at times; I don't think the question is unreasonable.

Comment: @Noldorin,I didn't ask when it will be released,I asked if C# v4 will be included in VS2010 and is C# v4 included in the current Beta1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# 4.0 is included in the VS2010 beta (you can try it right now; 'dynamic`, variance etc work), and will be shipped in VS2010 RTM and almost certainly (I assume) in the standalone .NET 4.0 RTM - but **when** that is is entirely up to Microsoft; in particular, [Soma highlights](http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2009/05/18/visual-studio-2010-and-net-fx-4-beta-1-ships.aspx) the need to get quality and performance right, and I would encourage them not to rush on either point (I want it fast and stable ;-p).

Comment: @Marc,what do you mean "will be shipped in VS2010 RTM"? If I download VS2010 Beta 1 from msdn,I will be able to use C# v4?

Comment: Yes, you can use C# 4.0 with the beta, hence how I stated "C# 4.0 is included in the VS2010 beta". By RTM I mean the final released product - I'm highlighting that the *final* release schedule is unconfirmed, and what you get *today* is just a beta/preview.

Comment: I've had a lot of fun playing with it so far, but it's still very beta.  :)  I'm _Really_ looking forward to the finished product.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the official release date of Visual Studio 2010 has not yet been announced. We know that .NET 4.0 and C# 4.0 will be released at the same time however, whenever it happens to be. A fair estimate for the release date might be Q1 of 2010. (The team seems to be on track with things, but it's not going to be released any earlier than the start of next year.)

Answer (score 1):

The current beta C# 4.0 mostly works, and almost looks like a final product, so I would expect the official launch to be october/november this year.

Microsoft are already actively showing off 2010 on any conference available.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear date for the release, it really depends on how many problems they find on the beta. However, there is no reason not to use the beta to develop software that will be released in the future, since there will be few changes to the API between now and the final release.